# Pandas & DataFrames calling dates associated with min & max outputs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have uploaded a xlsx file into python with this as an output:

```
Stock       Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume  \
0    FMG 2019-01-31  34.88  35.14  34.83  34.83  15402087   
1    BHP 2019-01-30  34.54  35.40  34.30  34.60  11832431   
2    ANZ 2019-01-29  33.50  33.79  33.49  33.74   7772463   
3    FMG 2019-01-25  32.72  33.12  32.72  33.05   7876508   
4    BHP 2019-01-24  32.53  32.78  32.45  32.62   6055049   
5    ANZ 2019-01-23  32.50  32.63  32.24  32.63   5777639   
6    ANZ 2019-01-22  33.04  33.13  32.76  32.77   5752232   
7    BHP 2019-01-21  33.25  33.40  33.20  33.20   8036600   
8    FMG 2019-01-18  33.11  33.30  33.07  33.11   9143363   
9    BHP 2019-01-17  32.90  33.04  32.77  32.87   5247991   
10   FMG 2019-01-16  32.90  32.93  32.71  32.93  10734470   
11   BHP 2019-01-15  32.70  33.07  32.60  33.06   5865704   
12   BHP 2019-01-14  32.70  32.97  32.62  32.71   8067488   
13   BHP 2019-01-11  32.95  33.01  32.67  32.79   6063635
```

I'm wanting to write some code that will return the .max() values (for the 'High' column) for each of BHP, ANZ & FMG and returning the data of which this occurred.

```
df = df.groupby('Stock').agg({'High':'max', 'Low':'min'})[['High','Low']].reset_index()
print (df)
```

returns this:

```
  Stock   High    Low
0   ANZ  26.31  23.81
1   BHP  35.40  32.24
2   FMG   5.65   4.13
```

Which is great but how would I get the corresponding dates associated with both the high & lows of each of the stocks when it occurred.

I'm fairly new and have been playing around with the functionality with data frames but to have this as output has been quite difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with  two `groupby` and `idxmax` + `idxmin` , notice the min of Low Date will not the same as max of High date

```
maxid = df.groupby('Stock').High.idxmax()
minid = df.groupby('Stock').Low.idxmin()
s = df.loc[maxid,['Stock','Date', 'High']].merge(df.loc[minid,['Stock','Date', 'Low']], on='Stock')
s
Out[166]: 
  Stock      Date_x   High      Date_y    Low
0   ANZ  2019-01-29  33.79  2019-01-23  32.24
1   BHP  2019-01-30  35.40  2019-01-24  32.45
2   FMG  2019-01-31  35.14  2019-01-16  32.71
```